# object to something

Tags: phrase-usage

Many dictionary example sentences give me the idea that "object to" is used to describe a negative reaction to something that hasn't been executed yet, such as a plan or proposal, or a general tendency. Could it be used to describe a fact, such as the following?

> Russia's invasion of Ukraine met with objections from many countries.

Comment: It would be an understatement if used of the countries that condemned it.

Comment: Could we object to something that has already happened and that is not a general tendency?

Comment: Yes, one can raise an objection after the fact. For example, one can object that a neighbor has erected a building that violates an ordinance in some way (e.g. it is too tall), and a municipality can demand that the building be taken down.

Comment: Watch a courtroom drama, where one attorney (barrister, should you prefer) offers a statement or evidence and the opposing one **objects to** that being introduced, after the fact. Or perhaps not -- if an objection is sustained, the statement or evidence is removed -- it never existed, is struck from court records.